# MYSQL Query to find changes in count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a great SQL query (provided by the very helpful FoxyGen) which returns a specific subset set of information from large set of metrics.

```
SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions), 
       MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time, 
       MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time
FROM metrics_tbl 
WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE 
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can append something to this existing query that will return only adjacent results which have a major negative difference in value.

For example, if the results are:

```
1. 2334 @ 12:01
2. 2134 @ 12:05
```

In this scenario, result 2 has a changed by a count -100.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Mitch

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference using variables in MySQL:

```
SELECT s, max_time, min_time,
       (case when (@x := @sprev) is null then NULL
             when (@sprev := s) is null the NULL
             else @x
        end) as sprev
FROM (SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions) as s, MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time,
             MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time
      FROM metrics_tbl
      WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
      GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @sprev := NULL) vars
order by max_time;
```

You can then test for whatever difference you like using a `having` clause:

```
having s - sprev >= 100
```

or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @gordon-linoff. Two questions, which I'm sure would easy for a second SQL'er. 1) I keep getting a syntax error when I run right syntax to use near _"FROM metrics_tbl WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE GROUP BY un"_, any idea why? 2) How would I incorporate the "Having" clause into this, assuming I'm going to run it from a PHP script? Thank you once again!

Comment: Fixed, the syntax error. `SELECT s, max_time, min_time,(case when (@x := @sprev) is null then NULL when (@sprev := s) is null then NULL else @x end) as sprev FROM (SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions) as s, MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time, MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time FROM metrics_tbl WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300) t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sprev := NULL) vars order by max_time;`. Just need to work on the having clause now.

Comment: You would put the `having` clause before the `order by`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: `SELECT s, max_time, min_time,(case when (@x := @sprev) is null then NULL when (@sprev := s) is null then NULL else @x end) as sprev FROM (SELECT SUM(metric_activeSessions) as s, MAX(metric_timeStamp) as max_time, MIN(metric_timeStamp) as min_time FROM metrics_tbl WHERE metric_timeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE having s - sprev >= 100 GROUP BY unix_timestamp(metric_timeStamp) div 300) t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sprev := NULL) vars order by max_time;`